# Possible to avoid cost increase in move to GCP MySQL Second Generation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I was using pay-per-use with MySQL first generation. It was a website with all I was using pay-per-use with MySQL first generation. It's for a website with all pages cached in memcached and only evicted from cache when I update content. Writes to SQL can also occur if somebody register for newsletter or similar (happens ~10 times/month). I was getting away for free with the pay-per-use model, but that model is not available in the second generation.

As far as I can understand, there is no way to get below $7 per month now with the new model. Is that correctly understood?

Or is there an API where I can turn on/off the SQL instance when I receive a registration or update content? It feels strange to pay so much for a service I use for less than a second 10-100 times per month.

Comment: Why the downvote? Should I formulate it differently?

Answer (score 1):

Minimal setup is about 7-8$ per month as you stated. You can check all the prices in the [Cloud SQL pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing).

If you don't want to pay it, you can use [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/) which is has a [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) available and it might fit your needs.